# Methods that return meaningful return values

Tags: c#

I work in C#, so I've posted this under C# although this may be a question that can be answered in any programming language.

Sometimes I will create a method that will do something such as log a user into a website. Often times I return a boolean from the method, but this often causes problems because a boolean return value doesn't convey any context. If an error occurs whilst logging the  user in I have no way of knowing what caused the error.

Here is an example of a method that I currently use, but would like to change so that it returns more than just 0 or 1.

```
public bool LoginToTwitter(String username, String password)
{
    // Some code to log the user in
}
```

The above method can only return True or False. This works well because I can just call the following:

```
if(http.LoginToTwitter(username, password))
{
    // Logged in
} else {
    // Not Logged in
}
```

But the problem is I have no way of knowing why the user wasn't logged in. A number of reasons could exist such as: wrong username/password combination, suspended account, account requires users attention etc. But using the following method, and logic, it isn't possible to know this.

What alternative approaches do I have?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create and return an `enum` with expected LoginResults.

```
public enum LoginResult
{
   Success,
   AccountSuspended,
   WrongUsername,
   WrongPassword,
}
```

Then return using the enum type in your method:

```
public LoginResult LoginToTwitter(String username, String password)
{
    // Some code to log the user in
}
```

Comment: @jvra If there are any unexpected exceptions, I believe they should be re-thrown as some of the other answers indicate. However, your code should be able to handle all of the expected cases: Wrong username, wrong password, account suspension, etc... and return those expected cases in the enum for your application to handle.

Comment: But the fact is, when you want to handle other error enum. your code could grow as grow your constants enum. but is a acceptable if you know that  in the future you could not have more constants enum.

Comment: @jvra I still prefer returning an enum in this case. It will handle all of the currently expected results in a strongly typed manner. If there are any that need to be added in the future, and you own the code, you can add to the enum. If you do not own the code and it needs to remain, then you end up handling the exception without being strongly typed anyway (which would be the other option, I believe).

Comment: Where is the Enum defined? I've defined it in my HTTP class that contains the LoginToTwitter method, and set the method to have a return type of LoginResult. But, in the Form class (which is where the http.LoginToTwitter method is called) the LoginResult enum is undefined. If I try doing LoginResult result = http.LoginToTwitter(...) the enum is undefined. So where is the best place to define the enum?

Comment: @JamesJeffery Is the enum set to public?

Comment: @JamesJeffery That can happen :)

Answer (score 8):

You could choose to either throw an exception with a relevant message attached (and have the calling method deal with the exception), or have the function return an `enum` with different states (such as `LoginState.Success`, `LoginState.IncorrectPassword`, etc.).

If you are using exceptions, it's probably best to have your function return nothing (`public void LoginToTwitter`), but if you're using an `enum`, make sure the set the return type to the name of your `enum` (`public LoginState LoginToTwitter`).

Answer (score 6):

There are two standard ways. If you're interested in just the outcome, but not any metadata, return some enum instead. Set the available values to `Success`, `Suspended`, etc. (all your possible outcomes)

If you need some more details, you can always use exceptions. Basically follow the "tell, don't ask" idea and write your function in a way that it returns required values (user id for example? or maybe nothing if you have some global login state) only on success and throws an exception with detailed description of the failure otherwise. Regarding the hierarchy itself, you should most likely implement a `LoginException` with some more specific subclasses and catch only those. (it makes it easy to verify all relevant exceptions are handled and all unknown ones are passed to higher levels)

Answer (score 3):

Both returning an enum or throwing an exception, as suggested in other answers, are reasonable.  But my preference is to *return an exception*.  Sounds crazy, but it lets your caller decide whether to use error checking or exception handling.  And, unlike the enum, exceptions are hierarchical, so it makes it much easier to handle entire categories of failures, and can carry arbitrary extra data.

I think Sayse had a similar idea, but he deleted his answer and never really explained it either.

Comment: So basically, `null` would mean *success* -- which seems rather counter-intuitive.  And of course if you actually need a return value, like (say) the user info...  I can see a good case for it in a language like Smalltalk, which is dynamically typed, but a statically typed language like C# makes this cumbersome.

Comment: @cHao: If further processing requires some other information to be returned, then throwing exceptions starts making more sense.  But if login failure is an expected outcome... well I don't use `throw` for non-exceptional conditions.

Comment: I'm semi surprised no one's considered a `LoginResult` type that isn't an exception, but also isn't just an enum.  It'd provide the flexibility of returning arbitrary info, without tempting people toward throwing exceptions for non-exceptional conditions.

Comment: @cHao: Or putting error information in an exception, and making that just one field/property of a `LoginResult` type (which as you say, avoids returning `null` and provides a place to put other results)

Comment: I actually kinda like that idea, possibly coupled with an easy way of throwing the exception if there was an error.  Like a `public void MustSucceed() { if (error != null) throw error; }` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

According to clean code tendency you should provide a meaningfull name for your method that reveal intent.

For to know what happened if logging operation could no be completed you can introduce  in your flow `Exceptions` and handle it in the caller context.

see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an idiom that is frequently used in c. The result of an assignment expression is the expression itself - this means you can capture a result code at the same time as evaluating whether it's a particular value:

```
if ((status = DoSomething()) == AnErrorEnum.NotAnError)
{//success handler
}
else
{//failure handler
}
```

I was asked to provide a link to an MSDN article - here is an old version of the spec:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315(v=vs.71).aspx

"The result of a simple assignment expression is the value assigned to the left operand. The result has the same type as the left operand and is always classified as a value."

Comment: It's in the spec, which is available for download: Here's the section of the old spec from 2003: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315(v=vs.71).aspx